# use regex to accept any string after users/ link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, devise, devise-confirmable

In my rails application I want to accept any string that comes after "users/" link. How do I do it? That is eg. `users/xyz` or `user/asdas` is acceptable. How do I do this?

---

```
def store_location
    # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
    if (request.fullpath != "/users/sign_in" &&
        request.fullpath != "/users/sign_up" &&
        request.fullpath != "/users/password" &&
        !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
      session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath 
    end
  end
```

Okay, here is the full story. I have implemented this along with letting user to sign in only if he is approved. The catch is I need to do it for only one type of user so I implemented this in `registrations_controller.rb` by overriding it.

```
 def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      # nil
      if !resource.has_role? :customer
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
  else
    resource.approved=true
    resource.save
    # nil
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

So customer alone can be directly approved but not others. So, when the users get the confirmation email and they click the link they get logged in but get confirmation token invalid error that is probably due to the page getting rerouted back to the confirmation token even on signing in and going to the root path which I have set in the `after_sign_in_path`. That is why I am trying a work around.

Is this the error or is this something else?

Comment: What have you tried? We need to see your attempt to build upon it, rather than spew some radically different solution that has to be shoehorned into your existing code.

Comment: I removed two expletives from your code comments. Please be aware there are many on Stack Overflow who take offense at such.

Comment: Sorry, I am not the one who works in the project. Will not happen again

Comment: it sounds like you have a XY problem...solution to the reroute question (Y) you have posted will not solve you real problem (X) of confirmation email not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem by using the following code. This make sure when the users clicks the confirmation link he is not redirected back to the confirmation link again on signing in as the confirmable module logs us in after confirmation right away.

I am using Rails 4, Devise version 3.03.

```
def store_location
# store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
if (!request.fullpath.match("/users/") &&
!request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return the string after "users/" or nil if it does not match:

```
def getUser(str)
  matched = /users\/(.+)/.match(str)
  if(matched != nil)
    return matched[1]
  else
    # did not match format
  end

  return nil
end
```

Check out the demo here: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/94766